# How to list view whole row selectable in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I created a sample application from Android sample tutorial and completed all 3 exercises for Notepad. I am able to add and edit notes created. However when I try to edit the notes I am force to select the text title for editing. If I click on to the right of the text, basically any where else In the same row I am not able to edit it.

I would like to make the whole row to be select-able/editable. Please let me know how to do this. I tried to change the notes_row.xml width="fill_parent". But this did not work out. Please help me out with this. Thank you.

Comment: You'll have to be a bit more specific. Can you show the layout that you're using for this row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change your notes_row.xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <TextView android:id="@+id/text1" 
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="TextView">
        </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```